# vscode use a single venv for many projects

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use vscode-insiders to debug about ten python projects. Each project has its own venv. Since they are projects that use the same graphics part, the difference between the various venvs is minimal but the space on HD is a lot (more than 5 gigabytes). What I would like to do is create a single venv complete with all the packages needed by the projects and make sure that this venv is accessible from the various projects

Comment: you can set the python interpreter for any project to the python.exe in any venv. No need to set the venv in a project, Use the command **Select Python Interpreter**